# Creating New MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am still newbie creating Database in Access, I am trying to build a simple database for Production Order. I have created some below tables and I am not sure how to link them.

```
TbleProduct
ProductID 
ProductDescription
CaseWeight

TbleOrder
OrderID
OrderDate
OrderQty

TbleInventory
ProductID
QtyonHand

TbleProduction
ProductionDate
ProductCode
ProductionQty
```

What I want to create a query which show, how much each product is on hand, and how many order are there for certain product, so can be schedule to produce.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a pretty simple SQL query, and maybe a homework question. Pleas post an attempt, or some research, or something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need design the table structure reasonably, the order table should be,
OrderID OrderDate OrderQty ProductID

Production table should be,
ProductionID ProductionDate ProductID ProductionQty

Then your application need maintain/update Inventory table based on order and production flow.

On hand product query is simple,
select  ProductID, QtyonHand from inventory

How many order for specific product,
select sum(OrderQty) from order where ProductID=your specific product id

Comment: I have one more tabeProduct, ProductCode, Description, Case weight

Comment: TGIF Half day going home :)